# Set custom font of AlertDialog buttons

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-alertdialog

I want to set a custom font for the positive/negative buttons of AlertDialog Builder. 
I am using Xamarin.Android.

I created the builder like this:

```
var alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(mvxTopActivity.Activity)
                .SetCustomTitle(CreateTitle(title, mvxTopActivity))
                .SetView(CreateMessage(message, mvxTopActivity))
                .SetCancelable(false);
```

I added the positive and negative buttons:

```
alert.SetPositiveButton(ok, (s, e) => { tcs.SetResult(okResult); });

alert.SetNegativeButton(cancel, (s, e) => { tcs.SetResult(cancelResult); });
```

I managed to set the font for title and message but I cannot set custom font for the buttons.

UPDATE:
I am trying to add the style after I create the modal"

```
 alert.Show();

            var mvxTopActivity = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity>();
            var font = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(mvxTopActivity.Activity.ApplicationContext.Assets, "fonts/Effra_Md.ttf");

            var btnYes = alert.FindViewById<Button>(Android.Resource.Id.Button1);
            btnYes.SetTypeface(font, TypefaceStyle.BoldItalic);

            var btnNo = alert.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.modal_button_cancel);
            btnNo.SetTypeface(font, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
```

I do not have access to Button1 but I do have access to modal_button_cancel/ modal_button_ok but it does not apply font like this.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I use to set the font of the `AlertDialog's` title, message, and button1.

```
Typeface semibold = ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, R.font.product_bold);
Typeface regular = ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, R.font.product_regular);
AlertDialog myDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Your title")
        .setMessage("Your message.")
        .setPositiveButton("Your button", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //your code
            }
        }).show();
int titleText = getResources().getIdentifier("alertTitle", "id", "android");
((TextView) myDialog.getWindow().findViewById(titleText)).setTypeface(semibold);
TextView dialogMessage = myDialog.getWindow().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
Button dialogButton = myDialog.getWindow().findViewById(android.R.id.button1);
dialogMessage.setTypeface(regular);
dialogButton.setTypeface(semibold);
```

Confirmed working on my Android 9.0, can't claim for it to work on older APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to achieved it like the following screenshot?

[image]

If so, first of all you should create a `Customlayout.axml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
     >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Alert"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dialog_title"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:text="This is message"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dialog_btn_cancel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="cancle"
            android:textColor="#AAAAAA"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dialog_btn_sure"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="Yes"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout >
```

Then, you could create a the `alertDialog`, there is code.

```
      //1.inflate the Customlayout
        View content = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Customlayout, null);
        //2. Getting the view elements
        TextView textView = (TextView)content.FindViewById(Resource.Id.dialog_content);
        TextView alertTitle = (TextView)content.FindViewById(Resource.Id.dialog_title);

        Button button1 = (Button)content.FindViewById(Resource.Id.dialog_btn_cancel);

        Button button2 = (Button)content.FindViewById(Resource.Id.dialog_btn_sure);


        //3. Setting font
        textView.SetTypeface(Typeface.Serif, TypefaceStyle.BoldItalic);
        alertTitle.SetTypeface(Typeface.Serif, TypefaceStyle.BoldItalic);
        button1.SetTypeface(Typeface.Serif, TypefaceStyle.BoldItalic);
        button2.SetTypeface(Typeface.Serif, TypefaceStyle.BoldItalic);

        //4.create a new alertDialog
        Android.App.AlertDialog alertDialog = new Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this).Create();
   
        //5. set the view
        alertDialog.SetView(content);
        
        //6. show the dialog
        alertDialog.Show(); // This should be called before looking up for elements
```

There is my demo.

https://github.com/851265601/CustomDialogDemo

Comment: @Kam  
Are there any updates for this issue? If the reply is helpful, please try to mark it as an answer,  it will help others who have similar issue.